# Count time when a message arrives from server (mqtt)

Tags: c++, mqtt, paho

I have a mqtt client that subscribes to a publisher. I have used the example code from [here](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp/blob/master/src/samples/async_subscribe.cpp).

The messages are published irregularly (not at regular intervals). I want to start a timer when a message arrives, so that I can call another function if "X" seconds have passed. Could someone please suggest me as to how can I do this(an example would be really helpful).

```
class callback : public virtual mqtt::callback, public virtual mqtt::iaction_listener
    {
        void message_arrived(mqtt::const_message_ptr msg) override
        {
            std::cout << "Message arrived" << std::endl;
            timerStart = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        }

    public:
        callback(mqtt::async_client& cli, mqtt::connect_options& connOpts, std::string topic)
            : nretry_(0), cli_(cli), connOpts_(connOpts), subListener_("Subscription"), TOPIC(topic)
        {
            tEth = std::thread(&callback::checkTimeBwMsgs, this);
        }
    
        double getElapsedTimeBwMsgs()
        {
            auto t_now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            elapsed_time_ms = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(t_now - timerStart).count();
            
            return elapsed_time_ms;
        }
    
        bool getIsData()
        {
            return isData;
        }
    
        void checkTimeBwMsgs()
        {
            double timeDur = getElapsedTimeBwMsgs();
            std::cout << timeDur << std::endl;
            if(timeDur > 1000.0)
                // do something
        }
    
        ~callback()
        {
            tEth.join();
        }
    };
```

The method 'message_arrived' is called when the client receives a message from the broker/publisher. I create a std::thread in the constructor which should be able to measure the time elapsed between 2 messages and if the time passed is greater than 5 seconds then call another method.

This method calculates the elapsed time only once. I want it to do it as long as the program is running. I am not sure if my approach is correct.

Is there any way in mqtt paho library that can give the time elapsed after receiving a message, whenever asked for.

METHOD 2:

```
int main()
{
    mqtt::async_client client(SERVER_ADDRESS, CLIENT_ID);
    mqtt::connect_options connOpts;
    connOpts.set_keep_alive_interval(5);
    connOpts.set_clean_session(true);

    callback cb(client, connOpts, TOPIC);
    client.set_callback(cb);
    
    std::thread tEth(ThreadFunc, cb);
}
```

Here, I create a thread in the main function and pass the object of the callback class as an argument. This gives the following error:

[image]

In method 2, my idea is to pass the class object as an argument. In the class, create a member variable that will save the time when the last message was received. In the thread above, I will then continously check for the elapsed time by calling the member variable through the class object.

Comment: `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles What I mean is this: When a message is received, the 'message_arrived' method is triggered. Then, I can start the timer. Now, when no message is received for, say, 10 seconds, 'message_arrived' is not triggered. But, I want to check if 10 seconds have already passed after the last message so that I can invoke another method which would then try to check if the connection to the broker still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, it sounds like the [Keep Alive](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901045) mechanism of MQTT is what you're after. Whatever broker you're using will have implemented this in one way or another.

On CONNECT, your client can specify a Keep Alive time in seconds. In your case, 10 seconds. This value is the maximum time that can pass between messages from the client and server. According to the spec:

> It is the responsibility of the Client to ensure that the interval between MQTT Control Packets being sent does not exceed the Keep Alive value. If Keep Alive is non-zero and in the absence of sending any other MQTT Control Packets, the Client MUST send a PINGREQ packet

This means, instead of your client manually checking if the server connection is alive, specifying this value should let the client library take care of this by periodically pinging the server.

Comment: the 'KeepAlive' mechanism would disconnect and then reconnect after every 'X' seconds. But, when the client is connected and the broker is closed, so no messages are recieved and this 'KeepAlive' mechanism is also not triggered. And therefore, I can not get the time passed after the last message.

Comment: Additionally, when the client is connected and the broker is closed, no messages are recieved and the 'KeepAlive' mechanism is also not triggered and the program seems to just wait for the next message in an endless loop

Comment: @Ankit KeepAlive does not disconnect and reconnect every 'X' seconds. The client should be sending a PINGREQ within that period to indicate the connection is still alive. Using the PINGREQ/PINGRESP pattern your client will know when the broker is closed.